# Is mumbai thane district flat property ownership name available online?

Tags: india, real-estate

I own a flat in Thane District near Mumbai. I would like to know if I can look up the ownership record online if I enter the address on a government provided facility.

Is such a facility available to have a look at the record?
Are Thane District Corporation available via email address, phone number or physical address? Is their phone service reliable?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Personal Finance question...

Comment: it is under category india real-estate... thank you verdammelt

Answer (score 1):

The Online Tax Payment website of [Thane Corporation](https://propertytax.thanecity.gov.in/TmcpropertyTax/Citizen/index.html) will give the details of the owners of the property once you enter the Property ID. There is no search via address.

Comment: How can i get the Property ID? I had registered this property back in 1996 I do not remember the registrars office that i went to.

Comment: It should be on the Index II that you would have got from the registrar. This would also be present on the property tax notice that Corporation would send every year. Older properties may not yet have got converted into electronic database.

Comment: Is there a way to reach the Corporation via email or address or phone? I live and work in US.